# ASP.NET MVC 2: Model Validation - username already taken?

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4

I am following Scott Gu's blog: [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx)

In his Blog he talks about client and server side validation.

How does one validate if username has already been taken and display this as a validation error message to the user?

In Scott's blog, this would be the same as validating if `Title` is unique:

```
public class Dinner
{
    public int DinnerID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a Dinner Title")]
    [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Title is too long")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the Date of the Dinner")]
    public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the location of the Dinner")]
    [StringLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Address is too long")]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your email address")]
    [RegularExpression(".+\\@.+\\..+", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid email address")]
    public string HostedBy { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RSVP> RSVPs { get; set; }
}
```

My first guess is that somehow this is done within the Model Controller, here:

```
    //
    // POST: /Home/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Dinner dinner) 
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) 
        {
            nerdDinners.Dinners.Add(dinner);
            nerdDinners.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(dinner);
    }
```

And because the `Title` is stored in a database server, this would be server side validation.

I know how to check if the `Title` is unique, but I do not know how to make the validation message appear in the View like it does using declaratives like `[Required]` or `[StringLength()]`. For example, here is how I can check for uniqueness:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Dinner dinner) 
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) 
        {
            foreach (var existingDinner in nerdDinners.Dinners)
            {
                if(existingDinner.Title == dinner.Title)
                {
                    **// TODO: display validation error message?**
                }

            }

            nerdDinners.Dinners.Add(dinner);
            nerdDinners.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(dinner);
    }
```

Using my imagination, and a magic wand, I would want to create a new declarative called `[TitleIsUnique]` that performs like the other validation declaratives.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Are you using the built in front end validation response as well? If so which one (MS one or the jQuery validation one?)

Comment: I am using the .Net one, which is a set of declaratives. Scott, in his blog, says they are from System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations library. I looked through this namespace and did not find a declarative that would do what I am asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a custom attribute as mentioned and use `IValidateObject` but I prefer to add my errors to the ModelState in one of the layers in my application.

For this you can use [ModelState.AddModelError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470776)

If you use `ModelState.AddModelError("Title", "Title must be unique");` it will add an error to the `Title` field.

If you use `ModelState.AddModelError("*", "Title must be unique");` it will add a general error message for the page.

```
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Create(Dinner dinner) 
  {
      if (ModelState.IsValid) 
      {
          if(nerdDinners.Dinners.Any(d => d.Title == dinner.Title))
          {
              ModelState.AddModelError("Title", "The title is not unique");
              return View(dinner);
          }

          nerdDinners.Dinners.Add(dinner);
          nerdDinners.SaveChanges();

          return RedirectToAction("Index");
      }

      return View(dinner);
  }
```

Comment: Do you know the answer to [this question?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568813/how-to-reference-html-page-from-aspx-page-in-the-same-vs2010-solution)

Comment: @sapbucket Was something wrong with my answer I posted there?

Comment: Hi Andrew, no, your answer was perfect. Unfortunately I keep getting stymied by MVC conventions. That was a long problem description for such a simple answer! Annoyingly someone -1'd my post, although as a newbie to MVC it is perfectly valid question (even if simple).

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking at implementing your own attribute derived from CustomAttribute. Take a look at this blog post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/05/27/ef-4-1-validation.aspx - it shows how to validate uniqueness. In the post IValidatableObject interface is used to perform validation but you should be able to the same by creating CustomAttribute.